# How to extract XML value and store it in CSV, with no XML tags?

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to extract `ID` values from an XML and save them to a CSV file. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<YourMembership_Response>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <ItemID></ItemID>
            <ID>92304823A-2932</ID>
            <WebsiteID>0987</WebsiteID>
            <NamePrefix></NamePrefix>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <MiddleName></MiddleName>
            <LastName>Smith</LastName>
            <Suffix></Suffix>
            <Nickname></Nickname>
            <EmployerName>abc company</EmployerName>
            <WorkTitle>manager</WorkTitle>
            <Date>3/14/2013 2:12:39 PM</Date>
            <Description>Removed from group by Administration.</Description>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemID></ItemID>
            <ID>92304823A-2932</ID>
            <WebsiteID>0987</WebsiteID>
            <NamePrefix></NamePrefix>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <MiddleName></MiddleName>
            <LastName>Smith</LastName>
            <Suffix></Suffix>
            <Nickname></Nickname>
            <EmployerName>abc company</EmployerName>
            <WorkTitle>manager</WorkTitle>
            <Date>3/14/2013 2:12:39 PM</Date>
            <Description>Removed from group by Administration.</Description>
        </Item>
```

I have been able to parse the API responses for `ID` with the following:

```
ID = tree.find('.//ID').text
print ID
```

which only gives me one `ID`, e.g. `92304823A-2932`.

I want to be able to loop through the `ID` tag to extract all the `ID`s.

This is what I tried, I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong but I don't even get an error message.

```
for node in tree.find('.//ID'):
    ID = tree.find('.//ID').text
    print ID
```

Secondly, I am not sure if I can write the `ID`s into a CSV within the same `for` loop.

**At a high level my question is how do I loop through all the `ID` tags in the XML and then how do I write those `ID`s to a CSV?**

Please let me know if my question does not make sense.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me:

```
with open("output1.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for node in tree.findall('.//ID'):
        writer.writerow([u' '.join(node.text).encode('utf8').strip()])
```